# CouchDB Rewriting

Tags: url-rewriting, couchdb

I have a URL for my website, which is as follows: http://ashgavs.cloudant.com/site/_design/AshGavsCouch/main/index.html

I added a field to my design document called rewrites and it's as follows:

```
[
   {
       "from": "",
       "to": "main/index.html"
   }
]
```

However when I go to this URL: http://ashgavs.cloudant.com/site/_design/AshGavsCouch/ . The rewrite isn't happening. Am I doing it wrong? Is there a way to see where its rewriting to so that I can debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [the docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Rewriting_urls) the default rewrite is *from* `/site/_design/AshGavsCouch/_rewrite`.  If you want the rewrite to be *from* `/site/_design/AshGavsCouch/` then you need to specify the URL in your `"from"` field.